# Hide ribbon when excel opens - excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide my ribbons upon my workfile opening.

I've followed the below link but keep getting run-time error 91.
[VBA auto hide ribbon in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201757/vba-auto-hide-ribbon-in-excel-2013)

I've written the following code on the "thisworkbook" mode, but cannot get the line to work.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
 End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Did you attempt the [2nd solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248134/5781745)? `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"`

Comment: I'm using excel 2016

Comment: Tested in 2016 - adding `Application.` in front of `CommandBars` seemed to resolve this.

Comment: ah brilliant why i didn't think of that, i do not know. many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `Application` in front of `CommandBars`.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
 End Sub
```

Comment: this is the answer many thanks to Kdavies

Comment: Don't thank me - was BigBen's suggestion. I also flagged to see if mod would merge with this question's dupe - unless you want to post this answer there and we can just close this as a dupe.

Comment: would be better to merge into other post i think, as this is a duplicate question just didn't adapt for 2016 version.

Comment: seems not to be a 2016 issue `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"` works for me in 2016 without error (in a module). But it fails in `ThisWorkbook`. So this is related to in which scope the code is placed.

Comment: Apologises thanks to BigBen.

Comment: Oh, Peh where did you add the code then? I tried in a worksheet and only works if i trigger that tab not when file was opened

Comment: @PGD15 In a module it works without `Application.` but not in `ThisWorkbook`. Anyway it is a very good idea to use it with `Application.`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah i used application for lots of my other code just didn't think to use it for this! :(