# How to hide ribbon with on event macro in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to hide a ribbon automatically when opening the workbook with this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"

End Sub
```

It is not working as on-event open workbook but it is working when i press F5, any advice? 
'

Comment: Try adding `AppActivate Title:=ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption` before your 'HideRibbon' command

Comment: Please see the comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310260/10908769