# Hide Microsoft Search in Excel Title bar

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

Microsoft has added a new feature referred to as, "[Microsoft Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/overview-microsoft-search)" with Office 365. When this is on, the search box takes up space on the Title bar. I'm looking for a way to hide it or collapse it using VBA or an API call. It doesn't appear to be part of the Office 2019 Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers. Minimizing the Ribbon does not help.
This is what I am referring to:
[Excel Search Feature Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3rtR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA minimize ribbon in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019546/vba-minimize-ribbon-in-excel)

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It is.. See the Microsoft Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36798

Open file called "excelcontrols"

Search for "MinimizeRibbon"

Comment: This does not answer my question. The new Microsoft Search feature is in the title bar. You can collapse it to a question mark in the title bar with File > Options > General > Collapse the Microsoft Search box by default. I would like to find a way to collapse or hide it using code.