# VBA to minimize ribbon with SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba, office365

As described in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019546/vba-minimize-ribbon-in-excel/19037071) I created the following VBA to minimize the ribbon menu in Excel:

```
Sub Minimize_Ribbon()
SendKeys "^{F1}"
End Sub
```

However, when I run this VBA it opens the following link to the `Help` section from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I assume this issue is because somewhow the `^` which should run the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not working in the VBA. 
What do I need to change to make it work correctly?

Comment: `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"`

Comment: or `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"` if you want to completely hide it.

Comment: Actually `SendKeys` is always the worst solution (if there are other options).

Comment: With `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon""," & "False)"` you _really_ hide the toolbar ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in the comments the solution is:

```
Sub Minimize_Ribbon()
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
End Sub
```